# Animated window icon

Tags: c, animation, icons, gtk

I have seen a rare amount of programs, having animated window icons.
From a distant vantage point, this could be rather beneficially isn't it..

I took the rudder in the process of inventing one function to do so.
It does what you probably thought of and using `Sleep()` to simulate intervals after each "frame".
I don't have to say that using WinAPI in major programs is a bad idea as well as the fact that the program will freeze until the function terminates.

Back on track. I am looking for a possibility to avoid this behavior.
It is understandable, hence no one wants a non-functional but take a note WITH ANIMATED ICON program.

Comment: Is this a GTK or a Windows application? You mention `Sleep` and the WinAPI, but the tag says GTK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably calling your function from the [Main Event Loop](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html). This is the thread where all sort of GUI events are handled, including mouse clicks and key presses. If you call `Sleep` from within this thread, all these processing tasks will be pending and your program will freeze.

To avoid this behavior, use [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add). This function will call a function at regular intervals from within the Main Event Loop (so no need to do it yourself). You need to define a function like this:

```
// define this function somewhere
gboolean animate(gpointer user_data) {
    // cast user_data to appropriate type
    // supposing you have a AnimationParameters class with everything you need...
    AnimationParameters* animParams = (AnimationParameters*)user_data;

    // update animation
    // ...

    return TRUE; // return TRUE to call function again, FALSE to stop
}
```

Elsewhere in your code, to start the animation:

```
AnimationParameters* animationParameters = new AnimationParameters(...);
g_timeout_add (30,  // call every 30 milliseconds
           animate,
           animationParameters);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will approve as it is the only answer. I just used gdk timer though. Thats how I dealt with it.. long ago already.